# visualize/browse/inspect nested hash-maps

Tags: clojure

Say a function returns a large and deeply nested hashmap. By which means do you study it's structure? Printing to the console is confusing, using clojure.pprint/pprint makes it a bit better but still does not give you an overview.

How would you handle it in order to understand it's data structure?

Comment: Have you tried https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.inspector-api.html#clojure.inspector ?

Comment: sounds promising, doesn't work on my machine though. It just creates a new blank window. That might be due to the fact, that I'm using a window manager (?).. A browser alternative could work better..

Comment: @AntonHarald are you sure it does not work ? It worked for me on Linux and OSX with Clojure 1.7 and 1.8. It uses Swing under the hood so should work everywhere Swing does.

Comment: yes the window manager is the problem.  have a look for the tool `wmname` and look up what a good setting is for your setup (i use LG3D for awesomewm)

Comment: I'm using awesomewm as well. After naming my wm via wmname to "LG3D" (inspect "sometest") still just creates an empty new white window /client in my windowmanager. In the window I cannot do anything, no right click etc.) Or would I have to restart the wm?

Comment: getting OT here, but this is a well known problem.  you have to search the web for how to fix it for your window manager version (another "fake" name can help).

Comment: I'm always using CIDER's value-inspection https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider#value-inspection  . It's vary useful/convenient for me and/or other CIDER users.

Comment: this looks like it could be the exactly the thing I was looking for. I see the inspected object in a new buffer when hitting the suggested key combination in emacs. However all the further key-combinations for navigating the structure don't have any effect. Do you know, why this could happen?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to inspect a map :

- [clojure.inspector](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.inspector-api.html#clojure.inspector) (as [@cfrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181392/cfrick) noted)

  ```
  (require '[clojure.inspector :as inspector])
  (inspector/inspect {:a 1 :b 2}) ;; #object[javax.swing.JFrame 0x1b730837 "javax.swing.JFrame[frame0,4,23,400x400,invalid,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=Clojure Inspector,resizable,normal,defaultCloseOperation=HIDE_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,0,22,400x378,invalid,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true]"]
  ```
- clojure [pretty-printing](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.pprint-api.html), note that you can [customize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4020186/1327651) it's behaviour. Also, don't forget that it easy to keep only the keys you want with [`select-keys`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/select-keys) or [`dissoc`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/dissoc), if you want to remove unwanted values.

Comment: For large hash map, `inspector/inspect-tree` looks better.

Comment: @ntalbs  I just put this example in case in the unlikely event he was calling the functions with bad parameters. Good point, though.

Comment: comes up in this fine video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QI9Fc5TT87A) along with other useful bits of clojure

Comment: @BWStearns This is where I saw it first, but I could not find it back !